# npm sibilings' peerDependencies error for React ^15.0.1

Tags: reactjs, npm

Not sure if it is related to upgrading to React ^15.0.1,  but now I'm having the following errors when installing any other npm package.  Any help would be highly appreciated...

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.0.1 wants react@^15.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-redux@4.4.5 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-test-utils@15.0.1 wants react@^15.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer redux-devtools@3.2.0 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-rc.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-create-fragment@0.14.8 wants react@^0.14.8
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-infinite@0.9.1 wants react@^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer redux-devtools-dock-monitor@1.1.1 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer redux-devtools-log-monitor@1.0.10 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
```

Comment: Looks like some of your deps are not prepared for React 15. Check for example `react-addons-create-fragment@0.14.8` - that's the one which needs upgrade.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm peerDependency - can't install package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584993/npm-peerdependency-cant-install-package)