# npm peerDependency - can't install package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm new to npm world, so maybe it's easy. The problem is the following:

I have a project with installed react `v.15.2.0`, and I need to install a package, e.g. `react typist` - https://github.com/jstejada/react-typist.
When I do it, I gen an error: (npm v2.*)

> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.2.1 does not satisfy its
>   siblings' peerDependencies requirements!

Reading on the internet, I followed an advice to update npm itself to v.3, so I did it by running `npm install -g npm`. But the error is still there:

> +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.2.1

I assume, that I need to update react to `v.15.2.1`, but don't know how to do it. Running `npm update` doesn't help, still same error. Could you please advice, how to solve the issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the most relevant parts of your project's "package.json".

Comment: What's `npm -v`? If you're using Windows, updating `npm` might not have worked as expected. Also, if you update npm, delete the whole `node_modules` folder and try again.

Comment: With npm v3 it's a warning and not an error. If you see it as an error you're still on v2. If you're on v3 it won't stop you from installing the dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version message is the other way around to what you're thinking. It's saying "the version of react that you have is 15.2.1 and that doesn't match what `react-typist` needs".

Indeed if you look in the [react typist `package.json`](https://github.com/jstejada/react-typist/blob/master/package.json) you'll see that they require version `0.14` of React. That's the problem. Looks like the repo hasn't been touched for almost a year, so you might want to pick something else, or fork it and make some changes.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answer. Actually, I'm not sure if I have react v.15.2.1, as in my package.json (see update to my question) it says, that I have 15.2.0

Comment: @berliner It doesn't matter. Any version 15.x.x would be incompatible with `react-typist`.

Comment: @berliner you should rather downgrade to **0.14**. Look for the warning below: `react-typist@0.3.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14 but none was installed.`

Comment: @berliner, what you see in `package.json` is like a 'range of acceptable versions' for the packages. Quite often the installed version will be newer than what's listed in `pacakge.json`. See [the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) for some handy info.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidGilbertson!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
If you want to update your npm package, you should do the following.

On your **package.json** file look for the line:

```
"react": "^15.2.0",
```

change the version number `15.2.0` to `15.2.1` and run `npm install`.
It'll update your react to `15.2.1`.

But the main detail you should have included in your question is the following warning:

```
react-typist@0.3.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14 but none was installed.
```

The recommended method is the one **David Gilbertson** suggested:

> Indeed if you look in the react typist package.json you'll see that
>   they require version 0.14 of React. That's the problem. Looks like the
>   repo hasn't been touched for almost a year, so you might want to pick
>   something else, or fork it and make some changes.

If you really want to use this component and function properly, you'll have to downgrade to `react 0.14`, which isn't recommended.

To downgrade use: `npm install --save react@^0.14`

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @TusharKhatiwada, you answer is pretty helpful as well!