# Upgrading npm project version to a release candidate - UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-shrinkwrap

So, I need to upgrade my npm dependency on "react" to 15.4.0-rc.4

I have tried both updating the value in my package.json to "^15.4.0-rc.4" and removing the dependency then running npm install react@15.4.0-rc.4 --save

The issue however is I always get this:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.0-rc.4
`-- react-number-input@15.0.0-rc2
  `-- react@15.3.2
```

I have overridden the dependency in my npm-shrinkwrap.json as follows:

```
{
  "name": "admin-console",
  "version": "4.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-number-input": {
      "version": "15.0.0-rc2",
      "from": "react-number-input@>=15.0.0-rc2 <16.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-number-input/-/react-number-input-15.0.0-rc2.tgz",
      "dependencies": {
        "react": {
          "version": "15.4.0-rc.4",
          "from": "react@>=15.0.1 <16.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-15.4.0-rc.4.tgz"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do to fix this dependency issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies

Comment: I have tried installing react directly as said in the question . Still got the error

Comment: `npm install react@15.4.0-rc.4 --save`

Comment: that is what I had executed. updating question

Comment: updated question. had the wrong version in the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm peerDependency - can't install package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584993/npm-peerdependency-cant-install-package)